# Wpf window shown using win32api ShowWindow ShowNoActivate doesn't render content

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi

I need to show wpf window without changing active window of other process. I'm using win32api ShowWindow with SW_ShowNoActivate (4) to show a window. However, content of the window is not rendered. I've tried to call window.UpdateLayout() and window.InvalidateVisual() after ShowWindow but with no luck.
How can I achieve it?

Here is a sample solution which shows my problem (VS2015) [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8N06JxC_Hl-bXcyRVgwMGZjVkk).

Expected: Label should be shown (shows "Test")

Actual: empty window is shown

Comment: The [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Interop/HwndTarget.cs,977) talks about a milcore bug workaround, that's pretty likely to be relevant.  These kind of hacks tend to only work when the sun is shining.  As suggested in the comments, you might avoid this by not needing a layered window and ensuring the window isn't minimized.

Comment: @HansPassant, could you please specify the line number? Yeah, you are right about this workaround, but I don't know any other way to show window without activation

Comment: @HansPassant, I think I've found relevant comment at line 981, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've found is to host wpf control inside of Windows.Forms.Form. I've tried to ShowWindow with ShowNoActive option and it does render wpf properly.